# How would I solve Level 14 (crispsContest.js)?

Tags: untrusted

There is not editable space in the code, or I just haven't seen it. o_O

If you aren't supposed to edit the code, how are you supposed to get the keys?

Any Help/Suggestions?

[image]

Comment: there is an editable space at line 47

Comment: This level comes up with a syntax error on line 27 for me. That's with absolutely no edits on my part - the very very first time I ever opened that level, the syntax error was there. Line 27 isn't editable. What the heck is going on?

Comment: Turns out there was a bug introduced yesterday sometime. The developer has now fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've figured out what you can edit:

> line 47

and what you can edit it to:

> theAlgorithm

You've got to get the Algorithm out.

> In the upper left, trade your blue key for a yellow key.  Then, in the upper right, trade your red key for another blue key.  Then trade the yellow and blue keys for the Algorithm at the bottom.

Answer (score 7):

write this on line 47

```
'greenKey');}return false;if(true){//'
```

Comment: I did something similar :P But I like yours more, feel more hackish :D `player.removeItem('redKey'); map.placeObject(22, 13, 'blueKey');`, then went top-left and directly for theAlgorithm. My solution used up to the last available letter.

Answer (score 4):

You can edit part of the command on line 47.

To beat the level...

> have the command try and remove 'theAlgorithm' [image: theAlgorithm]

Comment: Good find! Got it

Answer (score 1):

I overwrote the 'impassable' function:

```
greenKey')}},'impassable':()=>{if(!""){//
```

More beatiful; with context:

```
    'impassable': function(player) {
        if (player.hasItem('greenKey')) {
            player.removeItem(/*my code starts here*/'greenKey')
        }
    },
    'impassable': () => {
        if (!"") { ///*my code ends here*/');
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution used a ternary operator to decide which item to take, depending on the x position of the player:

> '+(player.getX()<25?'blue':'green')+'Key

With context:

> player.removeItem(''+(player.getX()<25?'blue':'green')+'Key');

Then, to get the algorithm:

> First, go through the blue lock to the yellow key (in the upper left). Then go through then green lock, get the blue key, and exit through the blue lock. Next, go through the red lock to get the blue key (in the upper right), go through the green lock, get the red key and go through the red lock. At this point you should have a blue key and a yellow key, which is all you need to get the algorithm.